# To simplify the code

Tags: asp.net

I confused: is there any way to simplify that code?

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pnlMain.Title) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title))
                pnlMain.Title = DefaultTitle;
            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title))
                pnlMain.Title = DefaultTitle;
            else  
                pnlMain.Title = Title;
 }
```

Comment: Note: you have a lot of questions without an accepted answer. You might want to look at accepting more answers...

Comment: @Chris, I'm reading now and translating. Sorry for my French.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you draw up a logic table for it you should be able to work it out... Have columns for true and false for `pnlMain.Title` being null or whitespace and rows for `Title` being null or whitespace and then in each cell mark whether you use the `DefaultTitle` or `Title` when you go through the above logic.

You should get the result that it doesn't matter what pnlMain.Title is.

So that code is the same as:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title))
            pnlMain.Title = DefaultTitle;
        else  
            pnlMain.Title = Title;
```

You can probably see it when you know the answer because in your code your first two checks are the same except with and without pnlMain.Title being checked as well and the same outcome.

From looking at what you might be trying to do you might in fact be wanting to do this:

```
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pnlMain.Title))
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title))
            pnlMain.Title = DefaultTitle;
        else  
            pnlMain.Title = Title;
    }
```

The above code will only change pnlMain.Title if it is null or white space and will use Title if that is not null or whitespace and otherwise fall back to DefaultTitle. This seems like more what I'd expect you to be wanting to do...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use ternary operator.

```
pnlMain.Title = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title))?Title:DefaultTitle;
```

You don't have to check `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pnlMain.Title)` because you are overwriting it anyway. But maybe it is another error in your code. So, what that piece of code meant to do?

Comment: @Johann Blais, <<The condition is wrong, you should reverse it >> what do you mean? Why is the condition wrong?

Comment: That's clear, but there are two options: 1. you set `pnlMain.Title` regardless of was it set before or not (and that code does exactly this) 2. you don't want to set `pnlMain.Title` if it was already set (in this case you have to check if it is set, and the first condition in first check in your question does exactly this). So there is some ambiguity here. What's the desired behaviour? `<<The condition is wrong, you should reverse it >>` I've already reversed it, so now it's OK.

Answer (score 1):

Your `else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title))` will always be true and the last `else` will never be reached. You probably meant something like this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pnlMain.Title))
    pnlMain.Title = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Title) ? DefaultTitle : Title;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is readable. Simplifying further, i.e. playing with `?:`, `||`, `&&`, would lead to unreadable code. Hence it is simple just enough.

Comment: Not true. There is a redundant logical check that can be removed to simplify it though I would agree that you don't necessarily want to make it as brief as possible since that affects readability. However, this code can *definitely* be simplified.